# Android xml layout parts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know if there is any method to specify in a "layout.xml" a reference to some "layout_element.xml" so that I can reuse some code.

This would help with headers, footers and other reusable blocks of "view".

Comment: Search for the `include` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently re-use complete layouts, you can use the `<include/>` and `<merge/>` tags to embed another layout inside the current layout.

`<include>` tag basically means ‘**take that file and paste it’s contents here**’

`<merge>` The layout which we have to use must be enclosed under merge tag, so that we can include layouts from other xmls.

my_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    // some views

    <include layout="@layout/repeated_layout"/>

   // probably more views

</LinearLayout>
```

repeated_layout.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    // the views to be merged

</merge>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two such constructs mentioned inside the docs.
The first is the [Include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) and the second is the [Merge](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) Tag(mainly for optimization).